# c# correct memory clearance or whatever

Tags: c#, testing, memory, allocation, garbage

I have some class ByteBitmap which contains inside private field byte[] bytes.
The main class Reader has a variable (like a cache) of ByteBitmap.
Reader implements IDisposable.

My problem is that variable breaks correct work of the Reader during tests.
I have > 2000 tests and this variable breaks some of them.
If i remove this cache variable tests are fine.

What is correct way to do in my case ?

PS if i run single test with this variable included - test runs fine.

```
   ByteBitmap _byteBitmapCache;
   internal override ByteBitmap GetByteBitmap()
    {
        if (byteBitmapCache != null)
           return byteBitmapCache;
        _byteBitmapCache = new ByteBitmap(_width, _height);
        for (int i = 0; i < _width; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < _height; ++j)
                _byteBitmapCache[i, j] = _binarizedBitmap.GetXy(i, j); // faster

        return _byteBitmapCache;
    }
```

Comment: How does the variable break some tests? What's the error? What is the cache supposed to do for you? Where's the relevant code?

Comment: Break seems because of uncleared byte array. i uanble to see an error because it happen during NUnit mass test in VS2010. Cache is the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `using` statement around reader, it will get disposed regardless of whether an exception occurs.

Here is the explanation from MSDN:

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an
>   exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can
>   achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and
>   then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the
>   using statement is translated by the compiler.